# if(X){if(Y){ versus if(X&&Y). Question about efficiency

Tags: performance, boolean, boolean-logic

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I'm not really sure what search parameters to use, so I'm going to ask here.

Let's say I have code I want to execute when both X and Y are true, and I want it to be as efficient as possible. There are two ways I know to go about this;

```
if(X)
    if(Y)
        //do stuff
```

Or there is:

```
if(X && Y)
        //do stuff
```

What I'm curious to know is how this code is actually read and executed at runtime? Is it more efficient to not check Y at all if X isn't true? Or is it more efficient to execute checks for X and Y at the same time? Obviously the second is more readable for humans, but if the only goal is efficiency, which is better?

Thanks!

Comment: In many languages the two are basically equivalent, but without knowing anything more than "any language", it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st case is more effective than the 2nd one.

The ASM code for the 1st case will be below type.

```
ax = A
if ax=0 goto address
ax = B
if ax = 0 goto adress
Do something
address:
..........................
```

but the ASM code for the 2nd case will be below type.

```
ax = A
bx = B
ax = A & B
if ax=0 goto address
Do something
address:
...........................
```

Answer (score 0):

In many (most?) languages, the two will be exactly the same.

If you care about performance, I assume you're using a good, optimizing compiler.  Any optimizing compiler should realize that when you write

```
if(X && Y)
```

then if X is false, it doesn't need to waste time evaluating Y.

This so-called *short circuiting* behavior is part of the definition of C and C-like languages.

Also, if you care about efficiency and performance, issues like this one are probably the last thing you should be worrying about.  It's very important that you pick a good language, and a good compiler for it, and choose good algorithms.  Fussing with low-level coding details, like `if (X) if(Y)` versus `if(X && Y)`, usually won't make much of a difference.

Also, if you *really* care about efficiency and performance, the only way to really answer questions like these is to perform careful measurements, using your code and your compiler and your computer, today.

And it can actually be quite difficult to perform good measurements.  Often, the two options will seem to have identical performance, which is another clue that "microoptimizations" usually don't matter at all.